# SQL query to find which step is completed which is not by customer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `customer` as shown below. In this table, `id` is the unique id of customer, all the steps which appear in this table are steps which are already completed by the customer. If a step is not in this table, it means this step hasn't been completed yet by this customer:

| Date | id | step_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 3 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 4 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-02 | 2 | 2 |
| 2020-01-03 | 3 | 1 |
| 2020-01-03 | 4 | 1 |
| 2020-01-03 | 3 | 2 |

I have another table `steps meta table` containing all the steps in the process:

| step_id | step_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | step1 |
| 2 | step2 |
| 3 | step3 |
| 4 | step4 |
| 5 | step5 |
| 6 | step6 |

Now I need to show for each id in `customer` which step is completed which is not. For this purpose I need all the steps to appear in the output table, if the step is completed,then the column "Step completed" should show a value of 1, if the step isn't completed, then a value of 0. Below an example of wished output for the customer with id1 from the `customer` table above:

| Date | id | step_id | Step complete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 4 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 5 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | 1 | 6 | 0 |

I am using SQL Server.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should be able to use a cross join/cartesian product with conditional aggregation to figure out what steps are missing for a customer.

Comment: You need a customer master table here. What happens if there is a new customer and they haven't completed any steps yet? They won't even show up.

Comment: what if some steps for a customer is completed on 2020-01-01 and other steps are completed on 2020-01-02, which dates should the missing steps contains? It looks like your design is lacking somewhat

Comment: @Olivia, if my answer is what you were looking for, could you please mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

Other users already pointed out some missing details on you question, which I agree exist. However, I made some educated guesses to address those in order to try to answer it.

Please see if this helps:

```
create table steps (
    step_id int identity
        primary key,
    step_name varchar(100)
)
GO

 insert into steps (step_name) values ('step1')
 insert into steps (step_name) values ('step2')
 insert into steps (step_name) values ('step3')
 insert into steps (step_name) values ('step4')
 insert into steps (step_name) values ('step5')
 insert into steps (step_name) values ('step6')
 GO
 
 create table customer (
    customer_id int identity
        primary key,
    customer_name varchar(100)
 )
 GO
 
 insert into customer (customer_name) values ('customer1')
 insert into customer (customer_name) values ('customer2')
 insert into customer (customer_name) values ('customer3')
 insert into customer (customer_name) values ('customer4')
 GO
 
 create table customer_steps (
    id int identity
        primary key,
    
    customer_id int,
    [Date] date not null,
    step_id int,
 
    constraint FK_customer_customer_id
    foreign key (customer_id)
    references customer (customer_id),
 
    constraint FK_customer_step_id
    foreign key (step_id)
    references steps (step_id)
 )
 GO
 
 insert into customer_steps ([Date], customer_id, step_id) values ('2020-01-01',1,1)
 insert into customer_steps ([Date], customer_id, step_id) values ('2020-01-01',1,2)
 insert into customer_steps ([Date], customer_id, step_id) values ('2020-01-01',1,3)
 insert into customer_steps ([Date], customer_id, step_id) values ('2020-01-01',1,4)
 insert into customer_steps ([Date], customer_id, step_id) values ('2020-01-02',2,1)
 insert into customer_steps ([Date], customer_id, step_id) values ('2020-01-02',2,2)
 insert into customer_steps ([Date], customer_id, step_id) values ('2020-01-03',3,1)
 insert into customer_steps ([Date], customer_id, step_id) values ('2020-01-03',4,1)
 insert into customer_steps ([Date], customer_id, step_id) values ('2020-01-03',3,2)
 GO
 
 select c.customer_id, c.customer_name, s.step_id, s.step_name, CASE WHEN cs.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as completed
 from dbo.customer c
 cross join dbo.steps s 
 left outer join dbo.customer_steps cs on c.customer_id = cs.customer_id
    and s.step_id = cs.step_id
 order by c.customer_id, s.step_id
 GO
```

Here are the results:

[image]